# When should I use UIComponent#popComponentFromEL(FacesContext context)?

Tags: jsf, uicomponents, facescontext

I'm working on an existing JSF component where the `encodeEnd` method ends with:

```
// popComponentFromEL(context);
```

The Javadoc for `UIComponent#popComponentFromEL(FacesContext context)` tells me:

> Pop the current `UIComponent` from the `FacesContext` attributes map so that the previous `UIComponent`, if any, becomes the current component.

When and why would you need or want that?

I've found that none of the other components in the same library are using it.

Comment: I think I've seen it being used in relation to the `p/ui:repeat`. Each child is pushed/popped so it can be processed  in the right context (line index, EL, etc)

Comment: @Kukeltje: Nope.

Comment: @BalusC: close enough ;-) hence just a comment. Did not have the time and code of mojarra at hand to figure it out... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the counterpart of [`pushComponentToEL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#pushComponentToEL-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-javax.faces.component.UIComponent-) whose Javadoc explains this more elaborately.

> #### pushComponentToEL
>
> `public final void pushComponentToEL(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)`
>
> Push the current UIComponent this to the `FacesContext` attribute map using the key `CURRENT_COMPONENT` saving the previous `UIComponent` associated with `CURRENT_COMPONENT` for a subsequent call to `popComponentFromEL(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)`.
>
> This method and `popComponentFromEL()` form the basis for the contract that enables the EL Expression "`#{component}`" to resolve to the "current" component that is being processed in the lifecycle. The requirements for when `pushComponentToEL()` and `popComponentFromEL()` must be called are specified as needed in the javadoc for this class.
>   After `pushComponentToEL()` returns, a call to `getCurrentComponent(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)` must return this `UIComponent` instance until `popComponentFromEL()` is called, after which point the previous `UIComponent` instance will be returned from `getCurrentComponent()`

Basically, this approach

```
public void encodeXxx(FacesContext context) {
    try {
        pushComponentToEL(context, this);

        // ...
    }
    finally {
        popComponentFromEL(context);
    }
}
```

allows you during the `// ...` process to grab `this` component using `#{component}` in EL, or [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-) in a managed bean.

One of [well known examples](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects) is this construct:

```
<h:inputText ... styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'valid' : 'error'}" />
```

where `#{component.valid}` basically refers [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid--).

Comment: Thanks. That makes me understand why it was commented and why I don't see it in other components (which extend existing components).